# Javascript error in animate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i tried to animate a div , its shows some error on the line shown below.

Here is the code..Is there any syntax error in this

> `$("#viewport").animate({margin-left:'50px'},"slow");`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DineshKanivu last I remember it was `Fiddle`?

Comment: @Hanky 웃 Panky Sorry Its Fiddle ....:):):):)

Comment: the error shows in the $("#viewport").animate({margin-left:'50px'},"slow"); line.. i think some syntax error occured

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have the `-` character in Javascript property literals (properties without quotes). jQuery offers a solution for this by converting camelCased names that reference CSS properties to dashed names. So you should change your animate object to `{marginLeft: '50px'}` or quote the property name like `{'margin-left': '50px'}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#your_div").animate({marginLeft: '50px'}, 500);
```

In your case

```
$("#viewport").animate({'margin-left':'50px'},"slow");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/rHd6C/358/)**